# How can I view HD videos without stuttering on PS3 Media server?

Tags: ps3-media-server

I'm running the PS3 Media Server on Ubuntu 10.04.  I can browse my shares, play movies, etc, usually without any problems.

However, some videos (like the ones recorded on my DSLR) do not play properly - it appears obvious that there's simply not enough bandwidth (PS3 is connected to the network via wireless).

Will running a wired connection fix this?  Are there any settings I can change in the Media Server to reduce the bandwidth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Running a wired connection will solve your stuttering problem.

Some other steps to improve streaming:

- Upgrade to [v1.10.51](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/downloads/list) If your not already using that version
- Set the Maximum Bandwidth in Transcoding Settings - > Common transcode settings - > Video quality settings to something your wireless network can handle.  (This will prevent high bitrate peaks from causing stuttering.)
- Don't transcode your videos.  Use the Ps3's built in decoder which has come a long way.  I hardly ever use the media server transcode anymore.
- Increase the size of the Transcode buffer
- Lower the video quality settings to: `keyint=25:vqmax=7:vqmin=2  /* Medium quality for HD Wifi Transcoding */`

You can also experiment with some of the newer beta builds but YMMV.

Comment: Going to a wired connection fixed things.  I tried playing with the max. bandwidth settings, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Nowadays "Video quality" has been renamed "transcoder quality," and is a dropdown.  There's an option for *"Wireless,"* but unfortunately that doesn't work for me - I need to set it to *"Low quality (Slow CPU)"* to get no stuttering on wireless for some videos *(my CPU is blazing fast, the only issue is the connection)*.  Despite the name, though, it doesn't actually look that bad.